# Testing Headers of Axios Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I'm using Mocha + Chai and [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) for testing my axios request. It workes well, but I don't know how to `test headers` of axios by axios-mock-adapter and make sure `Authorization` and `Content-type` is correct!

```
export const uploadFile = (token: string, fileName: string, file: Buffer): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject): void => {
    const uploadFileURL = `xxxxx.com`;
    axios
      .put(uploadFileURL, file, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      })
      .then((response): void => {
        resolve(response.data.id);
      })
      .catch((error: Error): void => {
        reject(error.message);
      });
  });
};
```

And this is my test function

```
  describe("uploadFile", (): void => {
    let mockAxios: MockAdapter;
    beforeEach((): void => {
      mockAxios = new MockAdapter(axios);
    });

    afterEach((): void => {
      mockAxios.reset();
    });

    it("should return item's id", (done): void => {
      const fileName: string = faker.system.fileName();
      const token: string = faker.random.words();
      const file: Buffer = Buffer.from(faker.random.words());
      const expectedResult = {
        id: faker.random.uuid(),
      };
      mockAxios.onPut(`xxxxx.com`).reply(200, expectedResult, {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      });

      uploadFile(token, fileName, file)
        .then((actualResult: string): void => {
          // I want to test my header of my requests
          expect(actualResult).to.equal(expectedResult.id);
          done(); // done make sure we know when we run the test
        })
        .catch(done);
    });
  });
```

So if anyone know how to write correct test for the header request, please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way by now is accessing request headers in `.reply` and validate it here:

```
mockAxios.onPut(`xxxxx.com`).reply((config) => {
  expect(config.headers."Content-Type").toEqual("What do you expect here");
  return [200, expectedResult, {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  }];
});
```

Actually I believe it should also be possible in declarative way:

```
mockAxios.onPut(`xxxxx.com`, undefined, { 
  expectedHeader1: "value1", 
  expectedHeader2: "value2"}
).reply(200, expectedResult);
```

So it would just throw instead of returning mock response if request headers did not match.

But it does no work this way by now.

Reason: `axios-mock-adapter` uses `deepEqual` for such a filtering. So we would need specify there not just few required headers(we are focusing on) but *all* headers including those axios adds on its own(like `Accept`). So it is not really readable.

I've [filed #219](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter/issues/219) in their repo on this. If it was not intentional for any reason, that may be fixed in future.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I dont think we need `mock` the `headers`, just return `[200, expectedResult], becuase in `uploadFile`, we use both Authorization and `Content-type`. But anyway, good answer!

Comment: @TranB.V.Son actually I did copy your code sample :) since I cannot know if something in `then` chain may rely on those headers present in response. But sure, if you don't need that you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

The declarative way mentioned by @skyboyer works with [objectContaining](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter/pull/181).

```
mockAxios.onPut(
  `xxxxx.com`,
  undefined,
  expect.objectContaining({ expectedHeader1: "value1", expectedHeader2: "value2"})
).reply(200, expectedResult);
```